# What's the correct way to rename a heroku app?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Doesn't seem to be a way to do it from the command line, and when I do this from the site, I run into this issue when I try to `git push heroku master`:

```
 !  No such app as [previous app name].
```

Is this as simple as changing how I point to the app in git?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Why use all caps?

```
heroku apps:rename my_new_app_name
```

Here is a great place to find out more:

[How to rename your Heroku application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps)

In case anyone is curious this method does not require any further configuration, your modifications should be immediate. At the time of this writing I was able to change the name of my app in seconds, and then do so again if I wished. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a better answer with more complete information and a link backing it up

Answer (score 68):

Did you try `heroku apps:rename NEWNAME`?

Comment: If you already changed it via the web interface, you just need to update the heroku remote's URL, which you can do with `git remote set-url heroku <newurl>`. You can get the new URL from the web interface.

Comment: @un5t0ppab13: Not required, just wanted to make it more clear that it was a variable piece of data.

Answer (score 14):

`heroku apps:rename new_name --app old-app-name`

^ worked for me

Comment: important for those of us who have more than one heroku deployment linked to a repo

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
heroku apps:rename --app old_name new_name
```

Comment: This is the updated Heroku command to rename the name of the app.

Answer (score 4):

If you are changing the name of the app on the webpage 
you should Updating Git remotes

`git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps

Comment: `heroku git:remote -a newname` will overwrite the existing `heroku` remote, therefore, `git remote rm heroku` is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

to rename app use:

```
heroku apps:rename --app <old_name> <new_name>
```

then, remove remote heroku:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

and add new one:

```
heroku git:remote -a <new_name>
```

and push changes:

```
git push heroku <branch_name>:main
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
heroku rename new_app_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
heroku rename new-name-app
```

always works for me but for additional information on rules, follow this [page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename your heroku app use:  heroku apps:rename new_name

Please replace "new_name" with the name you want to give your app. make sure you do not include any "https://" because this will give you an issue. simply replace new_name with your app name

e.g  heroku apps:rename grapefruitblog

After doing this, heroku requires that you  update git remotes for all other local checkouts of the app. you can do this by running this command: heroku git:remote -a new_name

Again, replace new_name with the name you previously put in

e.g heroku git:remote -a grapefruitblog